# Process flow with GUI and use of Shiny or not

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for some more general assistance on creating an app, I have old code that is VB6 that I am trying to ditch in favor of R, but the issue is that it requires some GUI control. I'm not sure that this requires a shiny approach as it's not really interactive in the sense that seems to be the strength of shiny apps, but because it requires a GUI I am struggling to find an alternative. Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Prompt user to load multiple files (easy enough without Shiny, number of files is not known could be anywhere from 1 to 100).
2. Read the files (also easy)
3. Build GUI with a row of controls for each file opened, controls consist of 4 checkboxes and two radio buttons. Default settings for controls (checked or not checked for check boxes) are created based upon file contents. User can over ride defaults.
4. Process the files according to GUI selections. Processing triggered by command button in GUI.
5. The final step and ultimate purpose is to write a new file based on user input

Thus there is no need for the traditional reactive shiny behavior of updating something whenever a control is changed. This is more a static GUI control in a sense. I've looked at gWidgets and some other non-Shiny controls but have not invested a lot of time in them yet. Hoping some recommendations will lead me down the right path.

Comment: There are multiple ways to escape "the traditional reactive shiny behavior of updating something whenever a control is changed". See https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/isolation/ is at least one of them that I can think of.